# Trying to send facebook notification, results in "sorry, something went wrong" response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-page

As from the title I am trying to use tha facebook notifications api. I have read the documentation and I am trying to do a POST to the graph like the one following:

```
String notificationURL = 
                "https://graph.facebook.com/" +
                String.valueOf(facebookUserId) + 
                "/notifications?" +
                "access_token=444146492324422|8LOOIj7xPT2LFlx14_3SqKCDgVc"  +
                "&href=https://apps.facebook.com/Nmctesting" + 
                "&template=@["+String.valueOf(facebookUserId)+"]! You have won!!";
```

the access token is the one returned from the graph query :

```
String appAccessURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=444146492324422"+
           "&client_secret=[MYAPPSECRET]" +
           "&grant_type=client_credentials";
```

I have tried to use the access token of the logged in user, who was the admin at that time, but It didn't work.

For any test that I do I get the html page as a response which states "Sorry, something went wrong"

what did went wrong?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [update] When tried this url on the facebook graph debugger :

https://graph.facebook.com/100005109698784/notifications?access_token=AAAGT8unnOkYBAECmCKt0Ae3OinFEMJHp7BX0yd0rmrOoCb2nVzYumuOozDzA5wC8GZBZCfTt5Rq0O2dGKZAifHuLvZBznhFgSrHBGKhjrRw0ZBcyNHJnm&href=https://apps.facebook.com/Nmctesting&template=@[100005109698784]! You have won!!

I got the response :
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Only web canvas apps can send app notifications", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}

Comment: [update] in th app settings, the facebook app, is ticked. So I think it is a facebook app. Furthermore, the call to the graph is executed by a facebook page tab. May this be the problem? Thanx!

Comment: Did you ever determine the root cause of this?

Comment: @stefan am trying to send app notification in the similar way, in my case app is a facebook tab, have a canvas url. But am getting the error "Only web canvas apps can send app notifications". Do u have any idea about the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your FACEBOOK_USER_ID is a valid facebook username.  You may need to URI escape it first. If it's the correct username, https://www.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_USER_ID will be the user's facebook page, so try hitting it in a browser before you try anything else.