# Frequent Graph API errors with non-JSON HTML responses: Sorry, something went wrong

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it 'normal' for the Facebook Graph API to frequently error out with a non-JSON error page such this. How much of this should I expect / need to build around? I'm within rate limits.

`https://graph.facebook.com/...../posts?access_token=<ACCESS TOKEN>&limit=25&until=1373675948`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="facebook">
  <head>
    <title>Facebook | Error</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="robots"              content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body {
        margin:       0px;
        padding:      0px;
        text-align:   center;
        font-family:  "Lucida Grande", "Tahoma", "Verdana", "Arial", sans-serif;
        color:        #333333;
      }

      a.menu {
        margin:     auto;
        position:   relative;
        display:    block;
        width:      964px;
        height:     29px;
        background: #3B5998 url('https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/common/error.png')
                    top center no-repeat;
      }

      .core {
        text-align: left;
        margin:     auto;
        width:      904px;
        padding:    1em 0em;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size:  18px;
      }

      p {
        font-size:  13px;
      }

      .footer {
        border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        color:      #777777;
        float:      left;
        width:      904px;
        padding:    5px 8px 6px 0;
        font-size:  11px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      function back() {
        if (1 < history.length) {
          history.back();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="menu" href="http://www.facebook.com/"></a>
    <div class="core">
      <h1>Sorry, something went wrong.</h1>
      <p>We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.</p>
      <p><a onclick="return back();" href="http://www.facebook.com/">Go Back</a></p>
      <div class="footer" id="pagefooter_copyright">
        Facebook &copy;
        2013
        &#183;
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/help/">Help</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this yet?

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872984/trying-to-send-facebook-notification-results-in-sorry-something-went-wrong-r/19102499

Comment: Any word on this, I am getting these errors and they are causing an exception in my backend. Is there something I can do to stop these HTML (non JSON) errors? If the username is invalid it should return a JSON error no?

Answer (score 0):

I never found out why these errors happen. I believe they are related to users from non-US. It seemed to me that they would persist indefinitely if I repeated the call.

I ended up throwing away these requests, by detecting if the result returned was a JSON object.

```
function isJSON(str) {
    if (typeof str === 'object') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```